# C++ reszing dynamic array works up to a certain number of elements, but at some point crashes with error (0XC0000005)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-arrays

Sorry if this has been answered before. I searched for resizing dynamic arrays and all the advice seems to be use STL Vector, but I'm doing an assignment where the point is to make my own, minimal, vector template class.

My vector class needs to store a dynamic array of structs created from reading from an input file. One of the things it has to do is resize when full. It works up to a point - processes 5121 lines out of 52207 lines and then crashes with error "Process returned -1073741819 (0XC0000005)".

I've looked around and found that this is a memory allocation error. I'm very new to programming and C++, and I'm stumped as to what in my program is causing this. I assume it is in my resizing the array code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My vector template code:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector {
public:
  /// Constructor
  Vector();
  /// Copy constructor
  Vector(const Vector<T>& otherVector);
  /// Destructor
  virtual ~Vector();
  /// assignment operator
  const Vector<T>& operator= (const Vector<T>&);
  /// methods
  void addElement(const T& newElement);
  T getElement(int index) const;
  int getLength() const;

protected:
  int arraySize;
  int length;
  T *p;

};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
  arraySize = 10;
  length = 0;

  p = new T[arraySize];
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector& otherObject)
{
  arraySize = otherObject.arraySize;
  length = otherObject.length;

  p = new T[arraySize];

  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    p[i] = otherObject.p[i];
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
  delete [] p;
}

template <class T>
const Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator= (const Vector<T>& newVector)
{
  if(this != &newVector)
  {
    delete [] p;
    arraySize = newVector.arraySize;
    length = newVector.length;

    p = new T[arraySize];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        p[i] = newVector.p[i];
  }
  return *this;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::addElement(const T& newElement)
{
    if(length == arraySize)
    {
       // create a new resized array
      T *temp;
      temp = new T[arraySize*2];

        // copy elements of p into temp
      for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        temp[i] = p[i];
      }

        // delete p and create new p and set equal to temp
      delete [] p;
      arraySize *= 2; // set array size to double
      p = new T[arraySize];
      p = temp;

        // delete temp array
      delete [] temp;

        // add new element and incerement length;
      p[length] = newElement;
      length++;

    }
    else
    {
      p[length] = newElement;
      length++;
    }
}

template <class T>
T Vector<T>::getElement(int index) const
{
  return p[index];
}

template <class T>
int Vector<T>::getLength() const
{
  return length;
}

#endif
```

Comment: First learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens and locate where it happens in your code.

Comment: Also, `p = new [...];` directly followed by `p = temp` is a *memory leak*. And then think about what `delete [] temp` does when you have *two* pointers to the same memory.

Comment: p = temp is using overloaded assignment operator, so should be doing a deep copy - have I done this wrong?

Comment: No there is nothing overloaded with the assignment operator in that. You're just assigning one pointer variable to another. It's not the `Vector::operator=` function being called there.

Comment: Thanks. I see that now. The assigment operator is overloaded on the class not the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your resize logic. Its all well and good until you get here.

```
p = new T[arraySize];
p = temp;

delete [] temp;
```

You allocate a new array and then immediately have `p` point to the data pointed to by `temp`. And then you delete the data pointed by `temp` which is the same as `p` which means `p` points to freed memory; it is a dangling reference and it is undefined to access anything through `p`

However, it is simple to fix: remove the allocation and deletion, you only need the line with the assignment:

```
  // p = new T[arraySize];
  p = temp;
  // delete [] temp;
```

You don't need new space for `p`, `temp` already got it. Just give it to `p`. And then you don't delete `temp`, because `p` is managing it.

Comment: @Aconcagua tried to make it more clear. if you have something better in mind you can make an edit :)

Comment: Hm, your explanation made my proposition redundant. Still added it to be more explicit, revert if you don't like it...

Comment: Thanks @vu1p3n0x, works a treat!. I was under some crazy perception that the assignment operator was overloaded on the array so the intent was several deep copies - probably a waste of memory!.